# Integrating google maps into Blackberry app

Tags: blackberry, google-maps-api-3, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am new to Blackberry app development(Blackberry 7.1) .I need to integrate google maps into a native Blackberry application.

1. Should I use Google API V2 or V3?
2. Are there any links or github projects readily available for
   reference?
3. Should Google maps be installed in the Blackberry device?

Another requirement is that

1) It should be possible to plot multiple points on the map

Comment: check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415140/blackberry-google-maps-sorry-we-have-no-imagery-here/13529953#13529953

Comment: @Signare: Are you using V2 or V3 of google api? Do you have the project hosted somewhere? I tried that code, but it is giving me error saying that it is not able to load the content for ""http://localhost"