# Show a map of India on BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, dictionary, java-me

I am working on a map application in BlackBerry. I am running BlcakBerryMapDemo app that run properly but when we put India's latitude and longitude and run app that is not showing map on Blackberry. Please suggest how to show a map with multiple pin points in BlackBerry.

I am using this code:

```java
StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("<lbs clear='ALL'>");

long number1=758839;
long number2=227277;
stringBuffer.append("<location lon='"+number1+"' lat='"+number2+"' label='Kitchener, ON' description='palasia,indore' />");            
stringBuffer.append("</lbs>");                                 
Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_MAPS, 
                         new MapsArguments(MapsArguments.ARG_LOCATION_DOCUMENT,
                                           stringBuffer.toString()));
```

`

Comment: Blackberry map is not available in india. you can use google maps.

Comment: for google maps, use my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415140/blackberry-google-maps-sorry-we-have-no-imagery-here/13529953#13529953

Comment: Thanks,but how to use Google map.Can you send me use full link or sample code of Google map.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415140/blackberry-google-maps-sorry-we-have-no-imagery-here/13529953#13529953

Comment: I have run that sample on BlackBerry6.0, first time it is not run and got error like java.lang.runtimeexception,application registry wait for (0xdfe7d338d7f0d) time out.But second time that code run and show map.But This code is not run on BB 5.0 and BB 7.0.